# javascript / jQuery: Get the appropriate heading for any element

Tags: javascript, jquery

given the following html structure (just as an example, it doesn't make that much sense):

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <h3>First Heading</h3>
    <div class="row"><div class="col-12"><p class="p1">Paragraph I</p></div></div>
    <input class="input1" type="text" />
    <ul>
        <li>First Item</li>
        <li>Second Item</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="b1">Send</button>
    <h3>Second Heading</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <p class="p1">Paragraph II</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <p class="p1">Paragraph III</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="wrapper1">
                <button class="b1">Click Me!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="b1">Cancel</button>
    <input class="input1" type="text" />
</div>
```

I want to get the appropriate "human style heading" (with pure js or jquery)- what a human would think that is the correct heading for an element. This is always the nearest heading by reading the document from the element upwards.

so for the first button (.b1 with content "Send") it would be "First Heading", for the second and third button .b1 it would be "Second Heading". The DOM is much more complex, the only reliable thing is, that the headings (h3 in this case) are always a direct child of div #wrapper.

I did several approaches with javascript closest, jquery parents(), nextAll() ... without success :(

Comment: _"I did several approaches with javascript closest, jquery parents(), nextAll()"_ - And where are they? Add the most promising one and explain the problems with it -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is it always an `h3`?

Comment: "h3 *in this case*" - how would any code know what a "human style heading" is, if you can't specify it?  Why is it not Paragraph I? (ok, not a child of #wrapper).  But if you add a `<p>` to #wrapper then could *that* be a "human style heading"?   What about an `<em>` or `<strong>` or anything else?

Comment: @ Andreas: These attempts were crap, just one-liner, that's the reason why I did not post them. No need no lock the question or downvoting! @connexo understood it pretty good and gave a working answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this would sort of work:

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');

for (const btn of btns) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(findNearestHeading(btn)));
}

function findNearestHeading(el) {
  if (el.previousElementSibling) {
    if (el.previousElementSibling.tagName === 'H3') {
      return el.previousElementSibling
    } else {
      return findNearestHeading(el.previousElementSibling);
    }
  } else if (el.parentElement) {
    return findNearestHeading(el.parentElement);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <h3>First Heading</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <p class="p1">Paragraph I</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input class="input1" type="text" />
  <ul>
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
  </ul>
  <button class="b1">Send</button>
  <h3>Second Heading</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <p class="p1">Paragraph II</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <p class="p1">Paragraph III</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="wrapper1">
        <button class="b1">Click Me!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="b1">Cancel</button>
  <input class="input1" type="text" />
</div>
```